# how to make redactor to not strip a specific regular expression

Tags: regex, smarty, redactor

I am using Smarty Template Engine and I need imperavi to not strip anything thats inside curly braces. So the code below would show:

```
<strong>{$entity->fullname|capitalize}</strong>
```

like

```
{$entity->fullname|capitalize}
```

in bold text but wouldn't convert it into

```
{$entity-&gt;fullname|capitalize}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the split_tag in php, it removes HTML tags for text (you can specify which tags to remove):
https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: Not what I was looking for but gave me a good idea :) I am going to preg_replace all the stripped content back; I wish there was a way redactor-js can have that functionality

Comment: Gah, don't use preg_replace! Throw it at a DomDocument and extract the textContent from nodes.